# Infer type of a parameter from another

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Given constant object implementing interface

```
interface Example {
  item1?: {
    item1?: string,
    item2?: string,
  },
  item2?: {
    item1?: string,
    item2?: string,
  }
}

const exampleObject: Example = {
  item1: {
    item1: 'test'
  }
};
```

how can I construct a function which will accept this object as first parameter, and the second parameter will have type based on object passed, not object's interface?

```
function exampleFunction<T>(a: T, b: ??) { // <- how to define second parameter?

}

// correct - type exactly the same as first object
exampleFunction(exampleObject, {
  item1: {
    item1: 'test'
  }
});

// incorrect - type not the same as the first object
exampleFunction(exampleObject, {
  item1: {
    item1: 'test',
    item2: 'test'
  }
});
// incorrect - type not the same as the first object
exampleFunction(exampleObject, {
  item2: {}
});
// etc...
```

Comment: You need to remove the type annotation from `exampleObject` for it to work.

Comment: That is unbelievably obvious now. Thank you

Comment: The problem with this approach is that I loose autocomplete on exampleObject. So the question is really, how to get a type derived from an exampleObject which implements Example interface, but without keys which were not specified, where all keys of Example interface are optional. Is this even possible or will the keys will have to be checked dynamically, whether they match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function should use a generic constraint and both variables should be the same type.

```
const exampleFunction = <T extends Example>(obj1: T, obj2: T) => {
  //do stuff
};
```

If you want typechecking and autocomplete for the variable `exampleObject`, then one workaround you can use is a generic helper function (which is also the canonical solution to this kind of problem):

```
function makeObj<T extends Example>(t: T) { return t; }

const exampleObject = makeObj({ /* intellisense */ });
```

However, **in TS 4.9+** we have `satisfies` which makes this much easier:

```
const exampleObject = {
     /* intellisense */
} satisfies Example;
```